# How do I jump to specific time with duration of an IIS streamed video in iOS?

Tags: iphone, iis, video, streaming, media

If I have a video streaming server (e.g. IIS Media Services) with a live video streaming, I want the user to select from a list of interesting parts of that video and then play just that bit.

For example, if I'm interested in a 25s clip 20m into the full length I want to jump to that bit and then close the video player at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answering my own question until someone betters it.)

There is an AVPlayer in the AVFoundation framework that can be used when you're after more sophisticated playback functionality.

On the IIS side, there is something called a PlayList that can be used to chunk up content that may work as an alternative.